# Reading Data in From MongoDB through Nodejs and displaying it through D3 Visualization in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar graph by reading data from my MongoDB collection through Node js and then feeding it through D3.js in Angular. I am not sure how to connect the Node js and D3.js in Angular to feed the MongoDB data.

This is my code in Angular:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createSvg();
    d3.json('http://localhost:4200/chart').then((data: any) => this.drawBars(data));
  }
```

This is my code in Node js:

```
const PORT = 4200;
//required installations
const axios = require('axios')
const express = require('express');
const res = require('express/lib/response');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');

/* This is where the Angular files live after they are built.  */
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './d3/dist/d3')));

var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/chart', async function(req, res) {

    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db("lab6");
    const coll = database.collection("player_stats");

    coll.find({}, { projection: { _id: 0, first_name: 1, last_name: 1 }}).toArray(function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Listening on *:4200');
});
```

This Angular code is based on this site: https://blog.logrocket.com/data-visualization-angular-d3/

The data is not displaying in the bar graph and I am getting a blank page.

drawBars function:

```
private drawBars(data: any[]): void {
      // Create the X-axis band scale
      const x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, this.width])
      .domain(data.map(d => d.Framework))
      .padding(0.2);

      // Draw the X-axis on the DOM
      this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

      // Create the Y-axis band scale
      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 200000])
      .range([this.height, 0]);

      // Draw the Y-axis on the DOM
      this.svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      // Create and fill the bars
      this.svg.selectAll("bars")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d: any) => x(d.Framework))
      .attr("y", (d: any) => y(d.Stars))
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", (d: any) => this.height - y(d.Stars))
      .attr("fill", "#d04a35");
  }
```

Comment: Angular? React? Decide.

Comment: You left database details in the code

Comment: @BojanKogoj Angular, and thank you I removed it.

Comment: Check the API response that you're giving to this. drawBars. It will be much easier if you also share the code of drawBars() function.

Comment: @Dignesh I have added that code as well.

Comment: Are Framework and Stars present in your data? It should be the data keys.

Comment: @Dignesh I switched it and it still does not work

Comment: Can you please share your data and also update the latest changes?